# Use the definition of compact set to prove the uniform continuity on compact sets.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

The question is: Recall the theorem

> A function that is continuous on a compact set $K$ is uniformly continuous on $K$.

Provide a proof by the definition

> $K\subset R$ is compact if every open cover of $K$ has a finite subcover.

Can someone tell me how to solve this question?

Comment: Is $K$ a metric space? How is this a linear algebra problem?

Comment: I am afraid K is not a metric space, I think it's a set of number like R. This question is raised in my Elementary Real Analysis class and we have not involved linear algebra in this class yet.

Comment: What definition of uniform continuity are you using?

Comment: A function f : A → R is uniformly continuous on A if for every ε > 0 there exists a δ > 0 such that for all x,y ∈ A, |x−y| < δ implies |f(x) − f(y)| < ε.

Answer (score -1):

This is a well known theorem, whose proof you can find in any analysis textbook, so I'll just give a sketch.

Suppose $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function and that $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact.

To use compactness, we need an open cover. Fix $\epsilon > 0$. For each $x \in A$, choose $\delta(x) > 0$ such that $y \in A$ and $|x-y| < \delta(x)$ implies $|f(x) - f(y)|< \epsilon$.

Define $N(x) = \{y \in A : |x - y| < \delta(x)\}$. These $N(x)$ form an open cover of $A$. Use compactness to choose a subcover $N(x_i)$. Take $\delta = \frac{1}{2} \min_i \delta(x_i)$. Suppose two points $x,y$ are $\delta$ close. Argue that $x$ is $\delta$ close to some $x_i$, and that $y$ has to be $\delta(x_i)$ close to that same $x_i$. What can you conclude about the distance between $f(x), f(y)$ and $f(x_i)$?

Comment: This does not take OP close to the solution. Obtaining a  finite subcover for  a cover by small balls  and taking the minimum of a finite number of $\delta_x$'s still does not prove uniform continuity.

Comment: You're right. The proof is  more complicated than I remember. I'll expand my answer a bit.